# How to use group/group_by in Rails properly for Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, group-by, chartkick

I am trying to display completed tasks done my user's friends.
I have a function `friend?` that returns a boolean value

For Bar chart I need to use count

```
<%= bar_chart @completed_tasks.count%>
```

Here is how I try to get the desired data:

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed: true).select{|task| friend?(task.user_id)}
```

And after all I need to group it by user_id. How can I do it properly?

I have tried adding the following options:

1. `.group(:user_id)`
2. `.group_by(:user_id)`
3. `.group_by(&:user_id)`

but i don't get any data represented in bar chart. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fact that `.group()` works with ActiveRecord Relations. Task.where(...) is an ActiveRecord Relation, while select returns an array. Here is my solution:

```
arr = Task.where(completed: true).select{|task| User.find(task.user_id).is_friend?(current_user)}
      @completed_tasks =  Task.where(id: arr.map(&:id)).group(:user_id)
```